# Want to have click event on the .obj file shown on the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, dom, three.js

I have a .obj file on the web page using Three js. 
My aim is, when I drag the mouse left/right, the OBJ model should rotate which I am able to do so USING THREE.TrackballControls().
Next thing is, I want to touch on the specific points on that OBJ model and if the mouse is down on those points something would happen(like a counter increase which will be shown on the web page).
I have seen DOMevents for three js but it looks like it allows us to click on the whole object not on specific points on the objects.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a raycaster. (r69)

```
mouse_vector = new THREE.Vector3(),
mouse = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 1 };
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var dir = new THREE.Vector3();

function onMouseDown( event_info ) 
{
    event_info.preventDefault();  
    mouse.x = ( event_info.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event_info.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
    mouse_vector.set( mouse.x, mouse.y, mouse.z );
    mouse_vector.unproject(camera);
    var direction = mouse_vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize();
    ray = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, direction );
    ray.set( camera.position, direction );
    intersects = ray.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);

    if( intersects.length ) 
    {
        intersects.forEach(function(clicked) 
        {
            // Your stuff like
            if (clicked.object.typ == 'yourObject')
            {

                //Event on click..  
            } 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @mcode. This information has helped, but I think if I rotate the camera, then the intersection point between a ray and object will change right? As ray's origin is attached to the camera. What I need is even if I rotate the camera, a point on the object should give me the same coordinates irrespective of the camera rotation.

Comment: What I want to use is, if there are two points on the .obj file (one facing the camera and one not facing the camera) and I want to click on the one facing the camera. I should not be able to click on the point not facing the camera. Can we achieve this with raycaster?

Comment: Can you draw a sketch in Paint? It's hard to explain 3D Visualisation and hard to understand it.

Comment: You have to set the green canvas to the object coordinates of the point (e.x. Eye) coordinates (x,y,z) and update them everytime if the camera changes (in your render loop or your controls)

Comment: Do you mean that I should set the canvas coordinates to the eye coordinates in the .obj file?

Comment: No. Your 3D Model is an Object. You can attach the canvas to the world-position of the Object with the offset to they eye etc.

Comment: How can I do that, can you give a code example of that?

Comment: I am not able to figure out how to attach canvas to an 3D object(.obj) 
In that case if I completely rotate the 3D model 180 degrees my canvas should not be effective as it is behind the camera. Do you think we can achieve that with this?